# Coordinates of $m$-dimensional subspace can be permuted to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m\times 0\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $m$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
How can I argue that there is a $\psi_{\sigma}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ given as $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto (x_{\sigma(1)},\dots, x_{\sigma(n)})$ s.t.
$\pi(\psi_{\sigma}(V))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ where $\pi:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^{n-m} \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is the projection on the first $m$ coordinates?

[$\sigma:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ is a permutation.]

I tried to consider a basis of $V$ but failed to show they stay linearly independent under projection.
I suspect there is a straightforward explanation I am missing, appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the coordinate vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ of a basis of $V$ in a matrix $A$.
Since the column rank of $A$ equals the row rank, we can choose $m$ rows of $A$ which 
span $\mathbb{R}^m$. 
Now choose a permutation $\sigma$ which permutes these row indices to the first $m$ entries.

$\pi(\psi_{\sigma}(V))$ contains $m$ vectors with row rank $m$, which must be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @pyrogen